# I am trying to use join with update query but cant find the issue

Tags: mysql, database, join, sql-update

**Please help me to correct the syntax**

```
UPDATE
    user_shift_test
SET
    shifttime='01:00-21:00'
FROM
    user_shift_test
INNER JOIN swaps 
ON 
    user_shift_test.userid=swaps.csrid 
WHERE
    user_shift_test.userid=5
```

This error am getting

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM user_shift_test INNER JOIN swaps ON user_shift_test.useri'
>   at line 5

Comment: You need a SELECT to decide which rows to update in user_shift_test.  The correct syntax is UPDATE/SET/WHERE.  What you wrote isn't valid SQL, like the message tells you.

Comment: which column you are updating like "user_shift_test_date".Because "user_shift_test" is table name not a column name.

Comment: Set should always be after on clause and before where condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE user_shift_test
INNER JOIN swaps 
ON user_shift_test.userid=swaps.csrid and user_shift_test.userid=5
SET shifttime='01:00-21:00'
```

(*I am assuming that you are trying to do an update query using a JOIN*)

Comment: Thanks dude life savior :P

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE user_shift_test
SET shifttime='01:00-21:00'
WHERE userid IN 
               (SELECT user_shift_test.userid
                FROM user_shift_test
                JOIN swaps ON swaps.csrid=user_shift_test.userid
                WHERE 
                user_shift_test.userid=5
               );
```

Comment: This answer should be  explained. Please explain your answer, what was the problem with the query in the question?

Comment: SQL syntax is incorrect use https://www.piliapp.com/mysql-syntax-check/ for checking and check document for right syntax....

Answer (score -2):

this should do it

```
UPDATE user_shift_test
FROM user_shift_test
SET shifttime='01:00-21:00'
WHERE user_shift_test.userid=5
INNER JOIN swaps 
ON user_shift_test.userid=swaps.csrid
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. I just showed up. On an update with a join pattern, the set comes last.